# How to use scrapy loader processors for long functions?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm staritng to use item loaders and in the examples the loader processors like mapcompose are used, to clean text e.g:

```
clean_text = Compose(MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip()), Join())   
test = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
clean_text(test)
```

It returns:

```
u'item1 item2 item3'
```

Now, I wat a different output, for that same input I need the data separated by commas and since I'm working with .csv files I'm also quoting the text to not break the format.

```
'"""item1,item2,item3"""'
```

For that I wrote this function:

```
def quote_field(text):
    text = ','.join([v.strip() for v in text ])
    return '"""' + text.strip() + '"""'
```

How can I implement item loaders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. 
First you should understand `Compose` and `MapCompose` classes. `Compose` is meant for applying some functions to list of items, while `MapCompose` is used to apply some functions for every item in the list of items.

So you want:

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Compose, Join

clean_text = Compose(
    MapCompose(str.strip), # strip every item in list
    MapCompose(lambda item: f'"{item}"'),  # wrap every value in quotes
    Join(','),  # join all items in list as one using , as separator
)
```

If you test it:

```
test = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
clean_text(test)
#'item1,item2,item3'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also need the outher quotes: """ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' """ because this goes into on cell on a .CSVfile.

Comment: Then call map compose with a lambda func. See my edit.

Comment: At this point, does it makes sense to use MapCompose instead of defining a regular function like: quote_field?

Comment: It's completely up to you how you structure your codebase :) If you feel that you need this logic outside of this processor then defining a specific function is a great idea! Personally I like all processors and processor parts as functions in a separate python module so I can reuse them across different scrapy projects, but it's entirely up to your own taste and comfort level.